# new install > website is not comming after adding ups

Tags: site-collection, user-profile-service, web-application

I followed microsoft step by step process on adding "user profile service app", did the very last step as well. iisreset.

Now the web application's site collection is not comming

Also, user profile service does not come up. keeps on giving me the correlation error and nothing in the uls log.

I deleted ups and re-added and still the same error and site is not coming up.

Comment: If your site is not up, could you check whether the app pool in your IIS is started?

Comment: Have you followed Harbar's documentation on setting up User Profiles Services App?  http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx
Also, Microsoft has updated the Technet documentation on setting up user profile services : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx

As per poster above, If your Web application isn't coming up, there's propably an issue with the app pool. Most likely it's stopped. An App pool which is stopped would also be the only reason why an issue isn't logged in ULS.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how the User Profile Service App would have effected the primary web application. Ensure that your service account running the application pool has been granted rights to log on as a service and log on as batch service. Ensure the App Pool is started.

If by chance you installed SharePoint 2010 w SP1 then you will need to look to apply the December 2011 CUs to fix the UPS correlation error I've found the combined media has a bug with the UPS.